# Ajax form filter post by custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, ajax, wp-parse-args

I'm currently working on a site where users can search for apartments. I have a custom post type for the apartment posts, which contain several custom fields. I have a page where i list all of the apartments. What i want to do is have a form, containing check boxes, drop-downs and radio button, where the user can filter apartment posts by custom fields. For example by price or size. So when the users clicks on an check-box for example i want the result field to be refreshed. Much like this one [product-sort](http://www.asos.com/men/accessories/cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=4210&via=top#state=Rf997=4484,4079&parentID=Rf997&pge=0&pgeSize=36&sort=-1).

I know this can be done via the query, but i would like an AJAX function to filter the post without reloading the entire page. I have tried Ultimate WP Query Search Filter plugin but it didn't work that well.

I have done a lot of searching to find a solution, but i'm not a ajax/javascript master.

So can you point in some direction, maybe with some code to help me out?

Comment: Recommendation of plugins or themes or anything such is beyond the scope of this community. Please check [how to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what not to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Now please edit the question accordingly for seeking help from the community.

Comment: But here I can definitely share few old blogs regarding ajax calls in WordPress. hope its helps
[`Link one`](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tutorial-ajax-wordpress/)
[`Link two`](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Sorry about the request for plugins. My apologies, I will edit the post right away. I have read these 2 articles but I don't really know where to start.